# Dynamics FetchXML condition checking text field beginning with pattern "xxABC"

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml

In Microsoft Dynamics 365 FetchXML, is there a way to check a text field with the condition that it begins with "xxABC", where "xx" can be anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually possible (to my surprise).

I created a few Account records, named:

- "aacd"
- "abcde"
- "zxcdef"

Using `_` as the placeholder for single characters I got the desired result:

```xml
<fetch top="50">
  <entity name="account">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <filter>
      <condition attribute="name" operator="like" value="__cd%" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Under the hood this `like` condition appears to be translated into T-SQL. Take a look at the documentation [LIKE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and have fun!